# Get a page's photo albums

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am attempting to get photo albums (and photos) from a business page for which I am an admin user. Is this possible using the Facebook C# SDK?

I know I can get my photos (/me) but is it possible for a Facebook "page"?

Any help or examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about this : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ 
try : /page_id/photos

Comment: Ok I can use this to get a photo album e.g. "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=14533143118&id=501153118&aid=21264"

How do i get the photos inside a specific album, i can't see a way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: I always use dynamic object and f.e foreach (you don,t have photos, but links to photos). Here is structure how it looks like http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552%2Fphotos